# Error implementing Generic Class with Type Constraints

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0

I have a Generic Base Class that I want to allow one of two types `ITest` or `IBoldface`.

My Base Class looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseTestingCollections<T> where T : ITest, IBoldface
{
...
}
```

One of the classes that inherit it looks like this:

```
public class TestCollection : BaseTestingCollections<ITest>, ITestCollection
{
...
}
```

When I compile I get this error:

The type DomainLogic.ITest' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DomainLogic.BaseTestingCollections'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DomainLogic.ITest' to 'DomainLogic.IBoldface'.

Comment: Commas are not an **or**, they are an **and**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an either/or restriction can't be done (as I'm sure you've noticed, the comma is more like `&&` than `||`).  You can either make two different abstract classes with different names (one `BaseTestingCollectionsTest<T> where T : ITest`, the other `BaseTestingCollectionsBoldface<T> where T : IBoldface`), or remove the static restriction and put the check at runtime.  Or make one of `ITest` or `IBoldface` extend the other, or extend a common interface, if they share members.

Here's an example of checking at runtime:

```
public abstract class BaseTestingCollections<T>
{
    public BaseTestingCollections()
    {
        if (!typeof(ITest).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) && !typeof(IBoldface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you're not satistfying the constraint you've specified. `T` has to extend/implement *both* `ITest` *and* `IBoldFace`.

Your constraint doesn't mean that it has to extend/implement *one* of the types - it has to do *both*. A type argument has to satisfy *all* the type constraints in order to be valid.

See [MSDN on generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I'm about fed up with your "I'm going to answer this question 10 seconds faster than you" attitude. :D

Answer (score 3):

Per your own generic constraint, only those types which implement *both* `ITest` and `IBoldface` are suitable generic arguments for your `BaseTestingCollection` class.

It's not either-or, how could it be?  What happens when you call method `Bar` from the `ITest` interface on a `T` which only implements `IBoldFace`, which in turn defines no method `Bar`?  What is a compiler to do when faced with such a scenario?

There is no reasonable action to take.  Your constraints apply all at the same time to the generic argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can't express an "either-or" constraint like this with C# generics. Use a common base interface of some sort:

```
interface ITestOrBold {}
interface ITest : ITestOrBold {}
interface IBoldface : ITestOrBold {}

class BaseTestingCollections<T> where T : ITestOrBold {}
```

Obviously instead of `ITestOrBold` you should have some sensible abstraction.

Comment: Shouldn't `IBoldface` inherit from `ITestOrBold`?